# What to do when review queues won't let you do the correct thing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, review-audits

I have used all of my close votes for the day. However, some of the review queues (like "Triage" and "First Posts") still allow me to review questions/answers. When I come across a post that obviously should be closed or removed, what is the correct action to take?

The correct answer is obviously not "flag it for moderator attention", because a number of my flags were declined. The correct answer is also obviously not "continue without closing or flagging", since I just received an audit in "First Posts" that needed to be deleted as spam, but since I was not able to vote to close or flag, it was impossible to give a correct answer.

Comment: related at MSE: [Block First Post and Late Answer reviews when you can’t flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333059/165773)

Comment: Skip is always valid as is taking a break and simply not doing any more reviews.